# "Подпольная контрабанда" - тавтология? Или возможно?

Tags: тавтология

> В "Тальоне" Онегин и Каверин распивали контрабанду подпольную! Имени
>   Барбы-Николь Клико-Понсарден!

Понятно ли, что это шутка юмора? С учётом воспоследовавшей Варвары?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне понятно. Контрабанда подпольная - конечно, тавтология, но в художественных произведениях часто является не ошибкой, а худ. приёмом для усиления  какого-либо слова.Здесь ирония по поводу ребячества Пушкина. Тынянов в ЖЗЛ говорил, что он вёл себя в Петербурге как скромный подросток, а на самом деле они с дядюшкой ещё как "зажигали", эту подробность своей жизни он подарил герою.

Речь ведь о "Евгении Онегине"?

К Talon помчался: он уверен,

Что там уж ждет его Каверин.

Вошёл: и пробка в потолок,

Вина кометы брызнул ток...

Пётр Каверин – отважный гусар, страшный бретёр, веселый повеса и кутила, дамский сердцеед и хороший приятель Пушкина. А Talon – это модный петербургский ресторан ранних пушкинских лет, в котором Александр Сергеевич и прочая столичная златая молодёжь любили погурманствовать: "и Стразбурга пирог нетленный, roast-beef окровавленный, сыр Лимбургский живой, ананас золотой, трюфли, двойной бекас, винегрет", ну, и конечно, "Вино кометы" – шампанское, произведенное в год 1811-й, когда над Шампанью долгих 260 дней висела огромная комета. Она появляется у Земли раз в 3095 лет, так что Пушкин  подростком её видел.

А вот виноделы были довольны. Считалось, что в год ее появления урожай винограда будет обильным, сам виноград отличным, а вино – божественным. В 1811 году - накануне наполеоновского нашествия отношения России и Франции были плохие.  Царь установил торговое эмбарго и все поставки из Франции были запрещены категорически. Однако предприимчивая мадам Клико умудрилась таки доставить в Россию контрабанду из 10 тысяч бутылок своего шампанского, на которых красовалась этикетка «Vin de Bouzy, 1811, de la Comete». Представитель Дома Клико в Восточной Европе писал в Париж, что те, кто пьет шампанское 1811 года «очень скоро находит себя под столом». Вино Кометы было не только божественным по вкусу, но и исключительно пьяным. И славилось повышенными пенящими свойствами – пробки хлопали, как пушки:"... и пробка в потолок!"